# Framework-agnostic template engine

Tags: templates, language-agnostic

I have a project using nodejs, gulp and some npm libs where I use [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) template engine.

I also have a project using ruby, middleman and some gems where I use [slim](http://slim-lang.com/) template engine.

There are several goals for me to use a template engine:

1. Write less of template language that you would write in html
2. Be modular: mixins, blocks, extends, includes, etc.
3. Inject data: from JSON, yaml, etc. so having interpolation
4. Conditionals, code evaluation, iterations/loops

Pug does all of that, slim does 1 well, 2 badly, 3 and 4 badly. Some engines like erb or mustache do less stuff.

But even is those template engines are great they are language specific (pug for JS only, slim for Ruby only, haml for ruby only, etc.).

The only language-agnostic and framework-agnostic template engine I found is [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/).

(not really language-agnostic but more multi-languages, anyway)

But Mustache let you do only one thing 3. (Inject data from JSON with interpolation) but that's like erb you will have to write ton of HTML and you don't have 2. and 4. too.

Is there any language-agnostic/multi-languages template engines supporting 1., 2., 3. and 4. ?

**Edit**: this wikipedia page can help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_template_engines (to say no)

Comment: [m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html) Of course, there *are* reasons almost nobody uses it for this sort of thing...